# SPSS - alguem sabe como criar laços de repetição e que esse laços criem novas variaveis em um dataset?

Tags: spss

alguém sabe como criar laços de repetição e que esse laços criem novas variáveis em um dataset? se possível usando o Syntax do SPSS ou alguma outra função do software.

Comment: http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-loop-command/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, vc tem que vetorizar sua tabela e depois associar o loop com os vetores:

Exemplo:

```
* Programs to construct a SET of difference scores and sum scores . 

VECTOR X(4) / Y(4) . 
DO REPEAT V= V1 TO V4 / W = W1 TO W4 / X = X1 TO X4 / Y = Y1 TO Y4. 
COMPUTE X = V + W. 
COMPUTE Y = V - W. 
END REPEAT . 

VECTOR V = V1 TO V4 / W = W1 TO W4 / X(4) / Y(4) . 
LOOP I = 1 to 4 . 
COMPUTE X(I) = V(I) + W(I) . 
COMPUTE Y(I) = V(I) - W(I) . 
END LOOP .
```

link para esse e outros exemplos:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476044

Comment: cara muito bom ... vlws pela ajuda.